# can I specify the style of underlined text in html?

Tags: html, css

can I specify how text is underlined? For example can I make it underlined by a double line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customunderlines/) on custom underlines from A list apart

You can also try something like this.

```
.double_underline {
    border-bottom: 3px double;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place the line above or below the text:

```
text-underline-position: above;
```

There is however no double underline.

Comment: This is a proprietary Microsoftism.

Comment: @David: Right you are... They usually have the "there is no public standard" text on them, but this said that it was an extension and linked to the CSS spec, so it looked like a standard property until I read it carefully...